# Does Java automatically save an 'evaluate' statement in a predefined Java variable?

Tags: java, operator-overloading, concatenation

Say I perform a simple add/concatenation statement:

```
variable + newInput
```

Without setting the calculated value to a new variable, as in:

```
variable = variable + newInput
```

or

```
variable += newInput
```

Does Java have some sort of specifier to be able to use the computed sum or concatenated string?

Apparently in Python it is automatically saved in the implicit global variable `_` -which is implementable like

```
Print(_)
```

Is there anything like this in Java?

Comment: Python has a REPL.  Java doesn't.  So there's no need for such a feature.

Comment: Not in Java, no. You *could* do it in C++, with some effort.

Comment: In Python's REPL the last return value is put into the `_` global, which is not present in the Python interpreter for programs

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty sure it was 'ans' but i edited the question anyhow.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Java9 comes with a REPL. The specifier to be able to access the sum in that case would be $n where n is a sequence

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard that is... if it ever comes out! :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than just not saving the result, Java will outright [**refuse to compile**](http://ideone.com/LTMsV2) your program if it contains such a line, precisely because the result would be unsaved and unusable if it was allowed:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        1+2;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Main.java:5: error: not a statement
        1+2;
         ^
1 error
```

Java does not allow arbitrary expressions as statements, and addition expressions are not considered valid Java statements.

The expressions that are allowed as statements by themselves are [listed in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8):

```
ExpressionStatement:
  StatementExpression ;

StatementExpression:
  Assignment 
  PreIncrementExpression 
  PreDecrementExpression 
  PostIncrementExpression 
  PostDecrementExpression 
  MethodInvocation 
  ClassInstanceCreationExpression
```

Assignment, increment, decrement, method calls, and `new Whatever()`, all things with side effects or potential side effects. Barring possible side effects of an implicit `toString()` call, `+` cannot have side effects, so to catch probable errors, Java forbids addition expressions from being statements.

Answer (score 6):

**No**. It does not have anything like this. You have to assign the computed value to a variable, otherwise it will be lost and consequently collected by the garbage collector.

The best option is to use a special operator so not to use an extra variable but assign the result to an old one. This is a Shorthand operator.

```
Variable += NewInput
```

Comment: Really? thats probably why i couldnt find anything about it.

Answer (score 4):

You can for sure do:

```
variable + newInput
```

but the result of that operation must be assigned to a variable, if not, it will get lost...

the most you can get is

```
variable += newInput
```

whihch is similar to

```
variable = variable + newInput
```

Comment: the first half is what i was really asking, if the result will be lost or if there is some designated variable java saves them to. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The point is: the `+` operator in Java simply takes two operands and returns a result (either numerical, or as string concatenation).

Without assigning this result to something (like returning it from a method; or as shown in your example) ... it is like: the operation never takes place.

This operation doesn't have any side effects on its operands; and there is no way of accessing this result.

Beyond that, there is no *operator overloading* in Java. So it is also not possible to do some black magic that somehow stores the result of operation as side effect. You could theoretically add an **agent** to the JVM, that intercepts at runtime to do something upon an add operation, but that is more like: "technically possible", but nothing you would do in practical reality.

Other JVM languages, like Scala for example might use it implicitly - the last expression in a method is always returned, even when leaving out the return statement (in scala).

Answer (score 0):

The statement you show is evaluated and nothing is done with it.  Unless you bind a variable to the result, the evaluation occurs without effect.

This will not be flagged as an error by the compiler.

Comment: You might get an NPE if one is a boxed type and the other a primitive. So it's not *necessarily* a no-op.

Comment: A NullPointerExceptin is a runtime error, not a compiler error.

Comment: Which statement are you referring to? There is no valid java statement in the question.

Comment: The statement `variable + newInput`

Comment: While this is a valid expression [(jls-15)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html), it is not a valid statement as far as I understand [(jls-14.5)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5).

Comment: Specifically, this is a [AdditiveExpression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) (and may be a valid one depending on the types of the operands)